# Bootstrap navbar, button to look like the menu collapse button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap navbar for my site for my menu. It's only used for mobile devices so the menu is always collapsed, into a standard navbar collapse button. This is aligned right; what I want, is a back-button in the same navbar that looks just like the menu collapse button, just with a different glyphicon (chevron-left), aligned left. Any ideas as to how to achieve this?

This is the menu code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="meistro.html">Meistro</a></li>
            <li><a href="deelnemers.html">Deelnemers</a></li>
            <li><a href="jury.html">Jury</a></li>
            <li><a href="orkest.html">Het orkest</a></li>
            <li><a href="deharmonie.html">De Harmonie</a></li>
            <li><a class="stemmen" href="#">Stemmen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-nieuwsbrief">Nieuwsbrief</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example of the below: http://seanconnelly.me/bootstrap-standard-button-with-left-mobile-back-button

**Add a new Button right above your other button:**

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></button>
```

Note that I've added a new class called `navbar-left`.  You can rename this to whatever you want to (such as back-button).  I'm also using the glyphicon left chevron that ships with Bootstrap by default, you can change it out if you're using FontAwesome or something else.

**Add the CSS**

```
.navbar-left {
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
    padding:6px 10px;
}
```

Should be it -- tweak it from there to fit your purpose.  Hope this helps.

Comment: **Edit** - you can also just use `.pull-left` instead of writing that CSS